# Скриншот страницы браузера C#

Tags: c#

Помогите сделать скриншот бразуера, только без видимости вкладок и закладок.
Делаю вот так, а оно делает скриншот не всего окна.

```
Process.Start("chrome.exe", "http://google.com");
        await Task.Delay(3000);
        Rectangle bounds = Screen.GetBounds(Point.Empty);
        using (Bitmap bitmap = new Bitmap(bounds.Width, bounds.Height))
        {
            using (Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(bitmap))
            {
                g.CopyFromScreen(Point.Empty, Point.Empty, bounds.Size);
            }
            bitmap.Save("test.jpg", ImageFormat.Jpeg);
        }
```

P.S. webbrowser не предлагать, тк не все скрипты обрабатывает, даже со webBrowser1.ScriptErrorsSuppressed = true;

Comment: это изврат. нужен браузерный движок, а не браузер. Awesomium советую. (урок для vb.net: http://www.cyberforum.ru/vb-net/thread343195-page7.html#post6161906 для c# все почти так же) проще него только галимый WB, упомянутый выше.

Comment: Спасибо большое) перерыл весь интернет а о Awesomium ни слова) Теперь все работает

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Как подсказывает @DollaDollar, такое можно реализовать с помощью библиотеки Awesomium.NET. 
Установите в своей проект [Awesomium.NET библиотеку](https://awesomium.codeplex.com/releases/view/81241)(я для примера установил просто nuget-библиотеку Unofficial.Awesomium.Complete) и напишите следующий код

```
var webView = WebCore.CreateWebView(1920, 1080);
webView.Source = new Uri("http://www.google.com");

webView.LoadingFrameComplete += (s, e) =>
{
   if (!e.IsMainFrame)
        return;
   BitmapSurface surface = (BitmapSurface)webView.Surface;
   surface.SaveToPNG("result.png", true);

   WebCore.Shutdown();
};

WebCore.Run();
webView.Dispose();
```

Данный код

1. Создает объект [WebView](http://docs.awesomium.net/html/T_Awesomium_Core_WebView.htm) и загружает веб-страницу
2. подписывается на событие [LoadingFrameComplete](http://docs.awesomium.net/html/E_Awesomium_Core_WebView_LoadingFrameComplete.htm) - окончания завершения загрузки страницы
3. Сохраняет страницу(делает скриншот) в png-картинку в файл *result.png*

Comment: Спасибо, работает отлично, только есть одна маленькая проблема. При повторном вызове функции вылетает Exception (на var webView = WebCore.CreateWebView(1920, 1080)), мол надо сделать re-initialize.

Comment: @Nikita, строчки `WebCore.Shutdown()` и `WebCore.Run()` нужно убрать из этой функции, и вынести их вне этой функции. При запуске приложения вызывайте `Run()`, при окончании приложения(когда WebCore больше не нужен), вызывайте `Shutdown()`. Здесь они воткнуты для полноты примера.

Comment: смотрите, у меня есть консольное приложение. И я вызываю функцию с сайтом, что бы сделать очередной скрин. И куда их засунуть вне функции ума не приложу.

Comment: Nikita, можно написать такую функцию и использовать повторно           `var webView = WebCore.CreateWebView(1920, 1080);
                webView.Source = new Uri("http://www.google.com");

                while (webView.IsLoading)
                {
                    WebCore.Update();
                }
                BitmapSurface surface = (BitmapSurface)webView.Surface;
                surface.SaveToPNG("result.png", true);

                webView.Dispose();`